# Google Apps Script - How to parse response

Tags: google-people-api

I am using getBatchGet to retrieve contact names from a group.
This is worked well. However, I do not know how to parse the response. The below variable res contains the data that I want. Next, I want to get individual fields like displayName.
I suspect that I must use some form of JSON, but my code attempts failed.
how to I get the string value for displayName? Below is just a couple of code snippets.

```
var group_contacts = People.People.getBatchGet({
  resourceNames: item,
  personFields: "names"
  
});  

var res = group_contacts.responses;
Logger.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

The `People.getBatchGet` request returns an array of `PersonResponse` [objects](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/PersonResponse), and each one has this JSON representation:

```
{
  "httpStatusCode": integer,
  "person": {
    object (Person)
  },
  "requestedResourceName": string,
  "status": {
    object (Status)
  }
}
```

Going deeper into the `Person` [object](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.PersonMetadata), you can get the display name by  going to the `Name` [object](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Name) and getting the `displayName`.

So from the original response, you can get the display names by iterating per each resource and using:

```
group_contacts.responses[i].person.names[0].displayName
```

If there are multiple names, e.g. aliases, you have to iterate through the `names` array as well.